# Not able to apply filter on externalid to get a Customer record in NetSuite Restlet

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to perform upsert using external id for Customer record in NetSuite Restlet.
Since Restlet allows records to be loaded only by internal id, I have used search.create to apply filter using external id. I am getting the following error:

```
"name\":\"SSS_INVALID_SRCH_OPERATOR\",\"message\":\"An nlobjSearchFilter contains an invalid operator, or is not in proper syntax: externalid.
```

Syntax of the filter condition is correct because when I tried to filter a different field with the same syntax, it worked. Looks like somehow the externalid field is not filterable here. I am not sure why. Requirement is to upsert using external id and in Restlet itself.

Code:

```js
/** 
*@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType Restlet
 */
 define(['N/record', 'N/search', 'N/error'],
 function(record, search, error) {
     // Create a NetSuite record from request params
     function post(context) {
        try {
            // Get the external ID and other fields from the request parameters
            var externalId = context.externalId;
            var email = context.email;
            var companyname = context.companyname;
            var subsidiary = context.subsidiary;
            var taxitem = context.taxitem;

            // Add other fields as needed

            // Search for the customer record based on external ID
            var customerSearch = search.create({
                type: search.Type.CUSTOMER,
                filters: [
                    ['externalid', search.Operator.IS, externalId]
                ]
            });

            var searchResults = customerSearch.run().getRange({
                start: 0,
                end: 1
            });

            if (searchResults && searchResults.length > 0) {
                // If a matching record is found, update the existing record
                var customerId = searchResults[0].id;

                var existingRecord = record.load({
                    type: record.Type.CUSTOMER,
                    id: customerId,
                    isDynamic: true
                });

                // Set fields for the existing record
                existingRecord.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'email',
                    value: email
                });                
                existingRecord.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'companyname',
                    value: companyname
                });
                existingRecord.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'subsidiary',
                    value: subsidiary
                });
                existingRecord.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'taxitem',
                    value: taxitem
                });                
                // Set other fields as needed

                // Save the existing record
                var updatedCustomerId = existingRecord.save();

                // Return the ID of the updated record
                return {
                    success: true,
                    message: 'Customer record updated successfully',
                    customerId: updatedCustomerId
                };
            } else {
                // If no matching record is found, create a new record
                var newRecord = record.create({
                    type: record.Type.CUSTOMER,
                    isDynamic: true
                });

                // Set fields for the new record
                newRecord.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'email',
                    value: email
                });                    
                newRecord.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'externalid',
                    value: externalId
                });
                newRecord.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'companyname',
                    value: companyname
                });
                newRecord.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'subsidiary',
                    value: subsidiary
                });
                newRecord.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'taxitem',
                    value: taxitem
                });                
                // Set other fields as needed

                // Save the new record
                var newCustomerId = newRecord.save();

                // Return the ID of the newly created record
                return {
                    success: true,
                    message: 'New customer record created successfully',
                    customerId: newCustomerId
                };
            }
        } catch (e) {
            // Handle errors and return an error object
            return {
                success: false,
                error: e.toString()
            };
        }
     }
     return {
         post: post
     };
 });
```

Comment: Are you sure `externalId` contains a valid value?  You would get that error if it's empty.

Comment: Agreed, this is the error you'll get when `context.externalId` is nullish. Maybe log out what's in `context` to make sure it contains all the values you expect.

Comment: Oops. You both are correct. I was passing externalid through postman and in Restlet was reading it as externalId. Case was different for letter "i". Thank you, it has worked now after making it the same.